Undefined reference to WinMain@16 Error when Compiling with MinGW
I am trying to compile a C++ program using MinGW, but I keep encountering the following error:
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o):(.text.startup+0xa0): undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Here's a draft for your Stack Overflow question:
Title: Undefined reference to WinMain@16 Error when Compiling with MinGW
Body:
I am trying to compile a C++ program using MinGW, but I keep encountering the following error:
vbnet
Copy code
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o):(.text.startup+0xa0): undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
I did some research and discovered that this error is usually related to the entry point of the program. I tried multiple solutions, including suggestions provided by ChatGPT, but the issue persists.
Here are some steps I have already taken:
Checked if my code includes a main() function: The code does include a main() function, but the error suggests that the linker is looking for a WinMain() function, which is usually required for Windows GUI applications.
Tried compiling with different options: I attempted to compile with various flags (e.g., -mconsole, -mwindows), but the error remains unchanged.
Verified my project setup: I have ensured that I'm compiling a console application and not a GUI application.
Despite these efforts, I continue to face this issue. Has anyone encountered this before? Could there be something I'm overlooking in my build configuration?

Also, using an old 32-bit compiler ver 6.3 is perhaps not the best choice when the OS is 64-bit and the latest gcc is version 14.2

It's a well known quirk of MinGW that when it cannot find a main function it complains about not being able to find a WinMain function. Now why it can't find main is a different question, one that cannot be answered with the information given above. At the very least you should post the code and the commands used to build it.

At a guess you've not saved your code before compiling or you're not compiling the file you think you are
